# Default AJAX extension in VS 2010 does not work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I don't understand why my AJAX extension controls cannot be dragged into my code. When I drag one of the controls, nothing appear.

I tried to fix this problem by download the Ajax Control Toolkit, extract the AjaxControlToolkit.dll, create a new tab in ToolBox, select Choose Item, select AjaxControlToolkit.dll and press Ok. Then my new tab disappear. Or the tab remains, without any controls in it. However, when I check "Show All", the controls and disappeared tab does exist.

I need to use Ajax in asp.net. Really need help.

Comment: Try to:* Reboot VS

* Create manual markup (don't use visual editor). If there are any errors - post it here.

Comment: Well, I tried everything and it does not work. VS2010 can't recognize manual markup of AJAX.

Comment: Are there any error messgaes?
Also you can try to download and run some sample AJAX-project (from here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/NestedPopup.aspx for ex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. My Windows 7 does not have .NET Framework 3.0 which is required by teh AJAX Control Toolkit. After install the .NET Framework in Control Panel->Program->"Turn Windows Features on or off" and changing the project to .NET Framework 3.5, it worked.

Comment: What? What exactly did you do? I'm looking in my Windows Features dialog box, and the big check box next to **Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1** is checked, but there is no more. I only have a few items under my AJAX toolbar.